# Apple game center and Facebook finding friends iOS6

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, game-center

I'm mainly looking to clarify the following:

**1. I've been told that with iOS 5 and below, if you use Game Center to setup a multiplayer game, the functionality to 'find Facebook friends' (like in scramble with friends) is not built-in so you need a separate server of the sort to manage this action - is this correct?**

As per iOS docs:

*The Social framework (Social.framework) provides a simple interface for accessing the user’s social media accounts. This framework supplants the Twitter framework that was introduced in iOS 5 and adds support for other social accounts, including Facebook and Sina’s Weibo service. Apps can use this framework to post status updates and images to a user’s account. This framework works with the Accounts framework to provide a single sign-on model for the user and to ensure that access to the user’s account is approved.
The UIKit framework also provides a new UIActivityViewController class for displaying actions that the user might perform on some selected content. One use of this class is to allow the user to post content to social accounts, such as Twitter or Facebook. You present this class modally on iPhone or using a popover controller on iPad. When the user taps one of the buttons, the view controller presents a new interface to perform the associated action.
For more information about the Social framework, see Social Framework Reference. For information about the UIActivityViewController class, see UIKit Framework Reference.*

Ref:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011812-SW1

**2.
Judging by above it appears that the 'find Facebook friends' operation is built into Game Center in iOS 6 - is this correct?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the functionality as you describe (finding facebook friends to connect multiplayer matches) does not exist on iOS6, at least not yet.

What is included is a bit different and a lot less exciting. If you go to the Game Center application on your device, you now get a "suggested friends" list that is generated from your facebook friends and the contacts on the device.

getting the facebook friend matching functionality still requires you to set up your own servers sadly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kaan Dedeoglu. Would you know if there is an automated service (as in off the shelf service) to do this?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no out of the box service that does this.